# Find limit points of $ { x \sin(\frac{1}{x}) | x >0}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find limit points of $f(x)= x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x>0$.

The given set can be written as [$-1,1 $]. so limit points are the same as given set. Is this correct ?

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t understand what you mean with the vertical bar. Can you check your expression?

Comment: @Logos It is known as  " such that "

Comment: But i want  limit points or cluster points

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Logos https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point

Comment: @Logos not understood your last line

Comment: The range of $f$ is not $[-1,1].$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f\ge 0$ on $[1/\pi,\infty)$ and $|f(x)|\le |x|$ on $(0,1/\pi).$ Thus if $f(x)<0,$ then $f(x)\in (-1/\pi,0).$

Comment: why is $|f(x)|\le |x|$ on $(0,1/\pi) $ ?

Comment: $|f(x)|=|x\sin(1/x)|=|x||\sin(1/x)|\le |x|\cdot 1.$

Answer (score 0):

Given set is not [-1,1]. It is actually the whole **R+** . So if you are asking the limit points of set of all positive real numbers, then answer is **R+** itself. [Graph of x sin(1/x)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EZaj.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).